# How To Try All Possible Combinations Of Hex Values In C# Code?

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, hex, byte

I have the following parts of C# Code for example and other else if's, where input_byte == have different Hex Values after the == :-

```
            input_byte = input_data[current_input_position];
            current_input_position++;

            if(input_byte == 0xFF) {
                //==============
                // Fin de chunk
                //==============
                Save();
                current_output_index++;

                RLE_sumador         = 0;
                line_min_length     = int.MaxValue;
                line_max_length     = 0;
                width_current       = 0;
                image_height        = 0;

            } else if(input_byte == 0xFE) {
                //=================
                // Siguiente linea
                //=================
                if(width_current < line_min_length) line_min_length = width_current;
                if(width_current > line_max_length) line_max_length = width_current;

                if(forced_image_width!=null) {
                    count = forced_image_width.Value - width_current;
                    if(count > 0) {
                        for(n=0; n<count; n++) {
                            output_buffer.Add(0);
                        }
                    }
                }

                image_height++;
                width_current = 0;
```

With the If and Else If parts of the code i.e. `input_byte == 0xFF 0xFE 0xFD` etc.. I want to alter the code, so I can brute force all possible combinations of individual hex values.

I think from 0x00 to 0xFF that is either 255 or 256 hex values. For example instead of 0xFF it could be 0x6E instead of 0xFE it be 0xFA etc. I have tried altering `input_byte ==` to different things in the hope I get something useful as an output image. This code was used on another DOS game, to save graphics images as greyscale bitmap images.

I using this on the previous DOS game in the series.

I was thinking of using:

```
For(int input_byte=0x00; 
input_byte <= 0xFF; 
input_byte++)
```

Somewhere in the code, but I don't think that would do all possible combinations of hex values.

I have Added the following to my Code :-

```
for (int i = 0x00; i <= 0xFF; input_byte++)
```

After

```
input_byte = input_data[current_input_position];
        current_input_position++;
```

And changed all input_byte ==
to input_byte == 0x00

And removed a line of Code, that saves Files other than .bmp's, so only .bmp's are saved, have I done the write thing here ? As I am not sure.

The unpac Program is still running after 30 minutes. So possibly I have made the correct amendments ?

I have changed to using this line of Code instead :-

```
 for (int i = 0x00; i <= 0xFF; ++input_byte)
```

From :-

```
for (int i = 0x00; i <= 0xFF; input_byte++)
```

After reading up some Stackoverflow posts, of what the differences are, between ++i and i++, the amended line of Code sounds more appropriate for what I want, I hope this brute forcing, method takes hours rather than much longer. Can someone clarify for me, if all the changes I have made to my C# Code, definately should work ?

I didn't get anywhere, with the above for loop, and I tried doing it the other way round i.e :-

```
for (int i = 0xFF; i >= 0x00; --input_byte)
```

or :-

```
for (int i = 0xFF; i >= 0x00; i = --input_byte)
```

i.e. working backwards, so changing all the five   input_byte == 0x00 to   input_byte == 0xFF.

When I run in either direction, the number in the brackets in the output in Command Prompt stays at (639) when going  0x00 to 0xFF, and (636) when it is the other way round. And the File Number just keeps going up and up. Whereas for other Ranges, I have tried small or large, i.e. loop from 0x00 to 0x01 but even as far as 0x00 to 0xFE, the number in the brackets changes, for each File output, and the Program runs for a few seconds. for either large or small ranges in the for loop, when I use :-

```
i = --input_byte
```

or :-

```
i = ++input_byte
```

Whereas if I use 0xFF, it goes on and on. The other hex value ranges small or large, do the same when I just use ++input_byte or --input_byte. I was getting the same outcomes when it was input_byte++ or input_byte--. I could really do with some help here, if that is okay ?

Could someone suggest, where I am going wrong with this, and what
changes, I need to make to my Code ?

Also how do I get the for loop, not to include all combinations of Hex Values that are numbers only ? As I know, these combinations won't produce saved .bmp Files.

i.e. all input bytes == are numbers only for each of the 5 input_byte == blocks of Code ? i.e both digits are numbers i.e. 00, 01 etc ?

Please can someone help me ?

Regards

Eddie Winch

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Comment: You real issue is how to convert your bitmap to different gray scale.  Using a for loop to enumerate through every value 0x00 to 0xFF will always give every value.  You need to understand bitmap better before asking your real question.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Comment: Would anybody else, be able to help me ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I expect people would be willing to help if you responded to their requests for clarifications. For instance, gunr2171 asked you to reduce the amount of code to a more reasonable amount. jdweng mentioned studying bitmaps some more as there may be better ways to get a solution. [Edit] your question to resolve those queries and perhaps more people would be willing to help. As jdweng already mentioned, you have the code to iterate through all values between 0x00 and 0xFF. What more, exactly, do you need?

Comment: Hi Heretic Monkey, Many apologies, for my lack of understanding, I assumed something else, from what jdweng said, i.e. about will always give every value, I thought he meant, would go through all Hex Values not all combinations of Hex Values too. Could you suggest what amendments to the code I have posted, I should do, i.e where to put the for loop ?

Comment: BTW: your for loop idea should be fine

Comment: pm100 so your saying, the changes I have made to my Code, should work, i.e. do what I want to do ?

Comment: Debug the code.  We cannot tell why the code is taking over 1/2 hour to run.  Usually in these cases there is something wrong with the loop counter.  You can add some Console.Writeline() statements to the code to debug.  Output the loop counter and see how far the code gets.  You can use menu : Debug : Break All to stop code and then hover mouse over variables to see current value when you break.  You can use F11 to step through code.

Comment: Many thanks, for your reply jdweng I will do, it could be due to the fact, there are so many possibilities of Hex Value combinations ?